# Read data saved by spark redis using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, redis, spring-data-redis, spark-redis

I using [spark-redis](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/java.md) to save Dataset to Redis.
Then I read this data by using [Spring data redis](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial):

This object I save to redis:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RedisHash("collaborative_filtering")
public class RatingResult implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8755574422193819444L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    private int user;

    @Indexed
    private String product;

    private double productN;
    private double rating;
    private float prediction;

    public static RatingResult convert(Row row) {
        int user = row.getAs("user");
        String product = row.getAs("product");
        double productN = row.getAs("productN");
        double rating = row.getAs("rating");
        float prediction = row.getAs("prediction");
        String id = user + product;

        return RatingResult.builder().id(id).user(user).product(product).productN(productN).rating(rating)
                .prediction(prediction).build();
    }

}
```

Save object by using spark-redis:

```
JavaRDD<RatingResult> result = ...
...
sparkSession.createDataFrame(result, RatingResult.class).write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
            .option("table", "collaborative_filtering").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save();
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RatingResultRepository extends JpaRepository<RatingResult, String> {

}
```

I can't read this data have been saved in Redis by using Spring data redis because structure data saved by spark-redis and spring data redis not same (I checked value of keys created by spark-redis and spring data redis are different by using command: `redis-cli -p 6379 keys \*` and `redis-cli hgetall $key`)

So how to read this data have been saved using Java or by any library in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me.

Writing data from spark-redis.

I use Scala here, but it's essentially the same as you do in Java. The only thing I changed is I added a `.option("key.column", "id")` to specify the hash id.

```scala
    val ratingResult = new RatingResult("1", 1, "product1", 2.0, 3.0, 4)

    val result: JavaRDD[RatingResult] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(ratingResult)).toJavaRDD()
    spark
      .createDataFrame(result, classOf[RatingResult])
      .write
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis")
      .option("key.column", "id")
      .option("table", "collaborative_filtering")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save()
```

In spring-data-redis I have the following:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RedisHash("collaborative_filtering")
public class RatingResult implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8755574422193819444L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    private int user;

    @Indexed
    private String product;

    private double productN;
    private double rating;
    private float prediction;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RatingResult{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", user=" + user +
                ", product='" + product + '\'' +
                ", productN=" + productN +
                ", rating=" + rating +
                ", prediction=" + prediction +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I use CrudRepository instead of JPA:

```java
@Repository
public interface RatingResultRepository extends CrudRepository<RatingResult, String> {

}
```

Querying:

```java
     RatingResult found = ratingResultRepository.findById("1").get();
     System.out.println("found = " + found);
```

The output:

```
found = RatingResult{id='null', user=1, product='product1', productN=2.0, rating=3.0, prediction=4.0}
```

You may notice that the `id` field was not populated because the spark-redis stored has a hash id and not as a hash attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already searched successfully by id, but in some cases, I want to search other fields (user,...). How can I implement?

Comment: I found the solution: find all keys -> find RatingResult by key -> filter by other fields:

`RedisConnection redisConnection = null;

try {

redisConnection = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection();

ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match("collaborative_filtering*")
      .count(100).build();

Cursor c = redisConnection.scan(options);

while (c.hasNext()) {

String id = new String((byte[]) c.next());

//TODO Find by id and filter
 }

} finally {

redisConnection.close();
}`